How does the mean function in this code produce the correct output, when it looks like it outputs a boolean not a float?
I can't work out how .mean() knows to calculate on the OVERALL_LI column in the final line in this code block.
import pandas as pd

education_districtwise = pd.read_csv('education_districtwise.csv')

mean_overall_li = education_districtwise['OVERALL_LI'].mean()
mean_overall_li

std_overall_li = education_districtwise['OVERALL_LI'].std()

lower_limit = mean_overall_li - 1 * std_overall_li
upper_limit = mean_overall_li + 1 * std_overall_li

#this is the code that confuses me
((education_districtwise['OVERALL_LI'] >= lower_limit) & (education_districtwise['OVERALL_LI'] <= upper_limit)).mean()

I understand that the column is being used to filter to just the rows within 1 stdev of the mean,  but not how the same column is having its mean calculated.
I tried breaking it apart using things like
(education_districtwise['OVERALL_LI'] >= lower_limit)

I assumed this would give me a list of numbers from that column, but instead it outputs
0       True
1       True
2       True
3      False

The code works correctly, I just don't understand why.
education_districtwise.csv:
DISTNAME,STATNAME,BLOCKS,VILLAGES,CLUSTERS,TOTPOPULAT,OVERALL_LI
DISTRICT32,STATE1,13,391,104,875564.0,66.92
DISTRICT649,STATE1,18,678,144,1015503.0,66.93
DISTRICT229,STATE1,8,94,65,1269751.0,71.21
DISTRICT259,STATE1,13,523,104,735753.0,57.98
DISTRICT486,STATE1,8,359,64,570060.0,65.0
DISTRICT323,STATE1,12,523,96,1070144.0,64.32
DISTRICT114,STATE1,6,110,49,147104.0,80.48
DISTRICT438,STATE1,7,134,54,143388.0,74.49
DISTRICT610,STATE1,10,388,80,409576.0,65.97

Breaking the code down into its elements to try and understand it better.

Why do you think it's calculating the mean of that column?

Beccause it outputs (below the cell in a Jupyter notebook) the figure of 0.6640378548895899, which is the correct mean for figures between the upper and lower limits if I filter and calculate in Excel.

it looks like values in OVERALL_LI are around between 65 to 80 (i understand you have more data overall), so even if you filter some rows, how the mean can be 0.66? right now you calculate the mean on a boolean column (combination of your 2 comparisons) and 0.66 makes sense if your distribution is almost normal. if you want to filter the rows and calculate the mean on the column, then you need to select the column, so something like education_districtwise.loc[((education_districtwise['OVERALL_LI'] >= lower_limit) & (education_districtwise['OVERALL_LI'] <= upper_limit)), 'OVERALL_LI'].mean()

When you call mean on a boolean mask, True is treated as 1 and False as 0.
So you're effectively calculating this:
(1 + 1 + 1 + 0 + 1 + 1 + 0 + 0 + 1) / 9 = 6 / 9 = 0.6667

Given the limits you used to create the mask, this is saying 66,667...% of the values in 'OVERALL_LI' are True in the boolean mask and therefore within one standard deviation of the mean.

I don't understand the problem, sorry.
With ((education_districtwise['OVERALL_LI'] >= lower_limit) & (education_districtwise['OVERALL_LI'] <= upper_limit)).mean() you are calling the mean method on a boolean series of numbers that return the True proportion on the total numbers of value.
You are not operating directly on the column OVERALL_LI but on the boolean series that derives from the conditions applied to OVERALL_LI.
I hope it would be the answer you were searching for.
